# Encouraging more questions

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, competition

One of the main reasons we're still in beta when other sites graduated is undoubtedly down to the low number [lack of questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/vegetarianism).

One idea to increase this might be to have some kind of weekly or monthly competition. We could decide what the competition theme is here on our site Meta and then have the competition question itself on the main site.

For example perhaps we could have a recipe of the month competition. We could decide on a theme of the week/month e.g. Thai food or recipes where lentils are the main ingredient or some other such restriction such that each month we get different recipes.

Other sites have tried something similar e.g.

- [photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/proposal-rules-for-new-photo-contest-on-main-site/)
- [seasoned advice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/deciding-the-scope-of-the-featured-question-for-asian-week)
- [mi yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/weekly-topic-challenge-5772-41-week-of-pinchas-5772-rashi)
- [security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stack-exchange-ctf-team)
- [reverse engineering](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/should-we-have-reverse-engineering-competitions-to-increase-site-participation)

at various points in their history.

Comment: Not sure three votes in two weeks while being featured is overwhelming support. Feel free to add other questions or answers with other suggestions for encouraging more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting best (top-rated) answers/questions of the year may be an idea.